# Accessing spring application name in custom starter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Im trying to access the spring application name in a custom starter auto-configuration.

```
@Configuration
public class CustomAutoConfiguration {

    @Value("${spring.application.name}")
    private String appName;

}
```

spring.factories as,

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=\
co.test.CustomAutoConfiguration
```

In an application that uses this custom starter I have defined the application name in `bootstrap.yaml`

```
spring:
  application:
    name: test-app
```

However, I'm seeing that appName is `null`. My guess is this has something to do with the order of loading ? Anyway to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what worked in the end.

```
@Configuration
public class CustomAutoConfiguration implements EnvironmentAware {

    @Override
    public void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
        this.environment = environment;
    }

    // And then accessing via this.environment.getProperty("spring.application.name")

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue in past and I solved by autowiring `org.springframework.core.env.Environment`; something like this:

```
@Configuration
public class CustomAutoConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    private Evinronment env;
    private String appName;
    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize(){
       this.appName = env.getProperty("spring.application.name");
    }

}
```

Not tested but it should work

Angelo

Comment: `PostConstruct` never gets called in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Might have something to do with the order in which `bootstrap.yml` gets loaded. We uaw `@Value` all the time in our `@Configuration` classes without issue, but we use `application.properties`. Have you tried setting it there? Or maybe on command line?

Answer (score -2):

I *believe* that your configuration class needs getters and setters for a private field annotated with `@Value`, in order for Spring to be able to set the field!